# When using the ReactGA npm package, do I need to import and initialize ReactGA on each individual component?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I'm currently working on adding google analytics to a small SPA(pplication). What I'm trying to do is basically register a bunch of click events to see when a user clicks on a certain button and occasionally a link. What I'm unsure of is whether or not I need to import and initialize ReactGA on each component, or if I can just initialize it on the main parent component and then just register the click events on the child components. I'm fairly new to React, so I'm anticipating that further clarification may be in order, so please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you in advance

-Not using React Router or Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with it yesterday, and it seems to work just fine with the `ReactGA.initialize()` call only being present in the parent component.